# Replace first occurrence of character not in the beginning of a word in a word using regex

Tags: java, regex

Example: 
"initial" should return "ineetial", "alumni" should return "alumnee" and "illuminati" should return "illumeenati"

However, using this code:

```
str = str.replaceAll("(\\w+)i(.?)", "$1ee$2");
```

I keep getting 'initeeal', 'alumnee' and 'illuminatee'  and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following `Pattern`, with a reluctant quantifier for your initial word characters:

```
String[] input = {"initial", "alumni", "illuminati"};
for (String s: input) {
    System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(\\w+?)i(.*)", "$1ee$2"));
}
```

**Output**

```
ineetial
alumnee
illumeenati
```

Answer (score 0):

**Why?**

Because `+` in `\\w+` is greedy by default. Add the reluctant quantifier `?` after `+` (`\\w+`) to do a shortest possible match.

Let us consider this example,

```
initial
```

regex ,

```
(\\w+)i(.?)
```

In the above `\w+` captures upto the last `i`(excluding `i`), so `init` would be captured by the group 1. Then the `i` matches the `i` after the `t`, then it captures the next character, ie. `a` into group 2(this would be an optional). So by replacing the matched chars with `$1ee$2` will give you `initeea` and the unmatched `l` would be added to the final result.